# Save HTML5 canvas as monochrome bmp

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas, bmp

I have an HTML5 canvas element which I would like to save to the server as a monochrome bmp. I have seen examples online of saving it as a color bmp, but because of size and colorspace restrictions my application has I need it to be a small monochrome bmp. Does anyone know of a simple solution for this (or am I going to have to write a class to create a bmp file from scratch?)

Comment: Bet you a nice JPG or PNG image would be even smaller than your monochrome bitmap...

Comment: Has to be a monochrome bmp because of what I am using the file for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution by working off of this example code: [rephrase.net/box/bitmap](http://rephrase.net/box/bitmap) The author helped me implement a function that could turn a pixel array into a monochrome bitmap. From there I was able to take canvas data and iterate through it and parse it into a pixel array that I could convert into a monochrome bmp.

I created this function to facilitate converting canvas data based on alpha values (since the canvas data is also monochrome in my application) to a pixel array which can be used by the jsbmp script:

```
function createBMP(canvas) {
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    var data = imageData.data;

    //create pixel array from canvas based on alpha
    var pixels = [];
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 4) {
        if (i > 0) {
            if (data[i] > 125) {
                pixels.push("000000");
            } else {
                pixels.push("ffffff");
            }
        }
    }

    //unmirror
    var pixarray = [];
    for (var i = height - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        var row = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            row.push(pixels[(i * width) + j]);
        }
        for (var j in row) {
            pixarray.push(row[j]);
        }
    }
    pixarray.reverse();

    return bmp_mono(width, height, pixarray);
}
```

And here is the code for bmp_mono:

```
/*
Create an uncompressed Windows bitmap (monochrome) given width, height and an
array of pixels.

Pixels should be in BMP order, i.e. starting at the bottom left, going up
one row at a time.
*/
function bmp_mono(width, height, pixarray, palette) {
var rowsize = Math.ceil(width / 8);
var rowpadding = 4 - (rowsize % 4);
if (typeof palette == 'undefined')
    palette = ['000000', 'ffffff'];

var j, pix, mod;
pixarray.reverse();
var pixels = [];
var b = 0;
for (var i=0; i<height; ++i) {
    row = [];
    for (j=0; j<width; ++j) {
        mod = j % 8;
        pix = pixarray.pop();
        if (parseInt(pix, 16) != 0) {
            b = b | Math.pow(2, 7-mod);
        }
        if (mod == 7 || j == width-1) {
            pixels.push(String.fromCharCode(b));
            b = 0;
        }
    }
    for (j=0; j<rowpadding; ++j) {
        pixels.push("\x00");
    }
}
return _bmp(width, height, palette, pixels.join(""), 1, 0);
}
```

Comment: Whats that `bmp_mono` function you're calling?

Comment: same as the bmp_rgb function in jsbmp except for a monochrome bmp.

Comment: Yeah, but where's the source for it? It's not really a good answer if there's a whole function missing, don't you think? :)

Comment: `bmp_mono` calls into `_bmp`, which is not defined here.

Answer (score 1):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/AjTuC/1/)**

This is a partial solution, as it does not convert it to a bitmap but a png. The first image you see is the canvas, the second is the original image, and the third is the data from the canvas put into an image.

if it *has* to be a bmp you could try checking this out for changing the data to a bmp

http://devpro.it/code/216.html